# How to prevent shutdown when low battery?

Tags: battery, system

When I'm using [my hacky backlight modulation program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955787/why-the-device-suddenly-shuts-down-itself-while-i-using-my-hacky-program) which toggles screen off and on fast enough to simulate ultra-dim brightness Android sometimes gets wrong info about battery charge (it sees 0% 0V sometimes for a short period) and starts shutdown unexpectedly for me.

How to turn off that shutdown on low battery?

Expecting something like:

- Changing settings to forbid this behaviour
- Temporarily locking battery reporting to some constant
- Temporarily making it think that it is charging

Root access is present.

**Update**: After updating from android 2.1 to android 2.3 it does not shut down anymore when I run that program.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68938/discussion-on-question-by-vi0-how-to-prevent-shutdown-when-low-battery).